# Are there any bootstrap like frameworks for android?

Tags: android

I love Twitter `Bootstrap` framework for web applications. Are there any such open-source `frameworks for android`? Like which provide all the `libraries, classes`, etc

Comment: Given that most people here are not web developers, you might want to explain what a `bootstrap UI` is.

Comment: By `Bootstrap UI` I mean the twitter bootstrap framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [Jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/). It's not exactly a framework but has ajax-based page transitions.

Supported Platforms:

> Android 4.4 (KitKat) – Tested on a Nexus 5
>
> Android 4.1-4.3 (Jelly Bean) – Tested on a Galaxy Nexus and Galaxy 7
>
> Android 4.0 (ICS) – Tested on a Galaxy Nexus. Note: transition performance can be poor on upgraded devices Android 3.2 (Honeycomb) – Tested on the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 and Motorola XOOM Android
>
> 2.1-2.3 – Tested on the HTC Incredible (2.2), original Droid (2.2), HTC Aria (2.1), Google Nexus S (2.3). Functional on 1.5 & 1.6 but performance may be sluggish, tested on Google G1 (1.5)

Hope that might help.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, you can use a `Theme`, which is a style applied to an entire Activity or application.
The Android platform provides a large collection of styles and themes that you can use in your applications. You can find a reference of all available styles in the [R.style class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html)

For more details about `Styles` and `Themes` look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)